# js remove google earth placemark

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having trouble writing script that adds then removes placemarks on Google Earth. Function `add ()` adds building placemarks by assigning placemark property to building `i` after I create placemark using script straight of api documentation:

```
var placemark = earth.createPlacemark("");
building[i].placemark=placemark;
```

When I called the function `remove()`, this removes placemark corresponding to user-selected latitude, longitude coordinates, if there is a building at those coordinates. Problem is, I'm getting the following error.

> "typeerror cannot read property placemark of undefined"

Yet `building[i].placemark` object exists and is not null.

Answer (score 1):

```
earth.getFeatures().removeChild(building[i].placemark);
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer, not just a line of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do know the method for removing placemarks. But before that, I need to verify there is a building at user-inputted coordinates, so I have a code that iterates through building array to check against latitude and longitude properties. It's at that point that I get an error saying object is undefined.